# Got a PEM lib error when using SSL key

Tags: ssl-certificate, tornado

## Background

I want to add a self-signed SSL key to a small http python server based on Tornado framework. I've followed [this manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html) to generate the SSL keys and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307131/how-to-create-https-tornado-server) to configure Tornado.

## The problem

Once the server receive a request it throws:

```
SSLError: [Errno 336445449] _ssl.c:369: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
```

## The questions

What is causing the above error? How can I fix it?