# TLS-enabled communication between intake client and intake server

Tags: nginx, intake

Within intake official documentation, it mention

> Authorization plugins are classes that can be used to customize access
>   permissions to the Intake catalog server. The Intake server and client
>   communicate over HTTP, **so when security is a concern, the most
>   important step to take is to put a TLS-enabled reverse proxy (like
>   nginx) in front of the Intake server to encrypt all communication**.

Can you advise any example on how to implement nginx in front of intake server ? What kind of nginx setup is required.

Answer (score 0):

It would take a small amount of work to enable HTTPS directly in the Intake server - basically allowing the setting of certificates in [this line](https://github.com/intake/intake/blob/master/intake/cli/server/server.py#L45) (example args like https://stackoverflow.com/a/18307308/3821154 ).

However, while this is not available, you need *SSL termination* at a proxy; and you might need to make your own certificates. This is a common use for proxies, and you can find many guides like:

- https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/
- https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#tls

These can be used in docker or any other isolated network - i.e., that the port opened by Intake is only accessible internally, not from the outside world, and it's the proxy's port which is exposed.